# Decrypt passwords from asp.net membership framework in nodejs

Tags: asp.net, node.js, encryption, cryptography, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to decrypt passwords from membership framework in a node.js app.

They are able to be decrypted as I get get the plaintext version from the membership framework `User.GetPassword()`.

I've tried the following, but this doesn't work:

```
let encryptedPassword = 'LqOz9My...';
let passwordSalt = 'JQ2...';
let validationKey = '0123456789ABCEF';
let decryptionKey = '0123456789ABCEF';
var algorithm = 'aes128';

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, decryptionKey);
var decryptedPassword = decipher.update(encryptedPassword, 'utf8', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
```

Comment: you're only encrypting passwords? ><

Comment: and what do you mean by "it doesn't work?"  meaning you're taking the encrypted password in your membership tables, running it through the decryption, then comparing that to `User.GetPassword()`?

Comment: @Kritner - exactly. I know what the plain-text version of the password should be. I think need to use the salt somehow. I've tried crypto.createDecipheriv, but my salt length seems to be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
let salt = '<my base64 salt>';
let saltBuffer = Buffer.from(salt, 'base64'); // 16 bytes
let decryptionKey = '<my hex decryption key>';
let decryptionKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(decryptionKey, 'hex');  // 24 bytes
var algorithm = 'aes192';
let encryptedPassword = '<my base64 encoded, encrypted string>';

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, decryptionKeyBuffer, saltBuffer);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var dec = decipher.update(encryptedPassword, 'base64', 'utf8');
dec += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log(dec);
```

The problem was that I was using the wrong encoding and wrong encryption. Here's how I figured it out.

#### Encryption

You can easily determine the encryption algorithm type via the length of your decryption key. In my case, once I converted the key to a `Buffer`, the length was 24, and because 24 * 8 = 192, my algo was `aes192`;

#### Encoding

In my original example, I had the *encoding of the encrypted password* as `utf8`. The encoding actually was `base64`. Not sure how to determine this other than trying the various accepted params.